# Como controlar duplicidad de creación de archivos en sqlite y C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

En la base de datos controlo los archivos insertados, como puedo controlar, que el registro que ingresa, no deba de ingresar nuevamente, puestos que cada 20 segundos se actualiza con un timer, pero el registro se dublica

[image: Duplica GenDETTXT]

Mediante este modulo inserto cada registro, como puedo controlar la duplicidad, que no se inserte 2 veces el mismo registro?

```
  public void SaveEstadoProceso(Entity.ENT_EstadoProceso estadoProceso)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(DbFile))
        {
            CreateDatabase();
        }

        using (var cnn = SimpleDbConnection())
        {
            cnn.Open();
            estadoProceso.ID = cnn.Query<string>(
                @"INSERT INTO EstadoProceso 
                ( ID, Fecha, Sucursal, GenCABTXT, GenDETTXT, GenXML, GenFirmado, GenZIP, GenSUNAT, GenEnviadoMail, GenFTP, RutaRespuesta ) VALUES 
                ( @ID, @Fecha, @Sucursal, @GenCABTXT, @GenDETTXT, @GenXML, @GenFirmado, @GenZIP, @GenSUNAT, @GenEnviadoMail, @GenFTP, @RutaRespuesta );
                select last_insert_rowid()", estadoProceso).First();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Es un código un poco extenso como para analizarlo entero, pero no veo donde compruebas que `GenCABTXT` o `GenDETTXT` es 1 para no actuar en ese caso.

Comment: Hola Karen y Bienvenida. Podrias ser mas especifica en que parte de tu codigo estas grabando esos registros?

Comment: gracias, acabo de detallarlo, espero puedan entenderlo y ayudarme en el lio que tengo, gracias de antemano

Comment: sigue siendo bastante complejo, tratemos de bajar el problema a un nivel menor. el problema esta al grabar el archivo o al hacer el update en la base de datos? si el problema es el segundo, detalla exactamente donde haces el update, y explica de que manera lo haces. si el problema es grabar el archivo, vamos por ese lado entonces. Estoy tratando de minimizar el codigo asi entendemos el problema mejor.

Comment: coloca como llave primaria tu ID y asi no te permite ingresarlo por segunda vez, te arrojara una excepcion la cual deberas controlar

Comment: Al controlarlo como llave primaria, no permite que se actualice

Answer (score 1):

Puedes prevenir el error y no hacer nada si el valor ya existe usando...

[insertWithOnConflict](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int))

...y puedes usar [CONFLICT_IGNORE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_IGNORE) para el parametro ConflictAlgorithm

Y si quieres actualizar una fila existente, puedes usar el mismo metodo pero con CONFLICT_UPDATE en ves del CONFLICT_IGNORE.

Comment: trabajo con c# y sqlite